# Extend a type with customized class

Tags: c#

I'm wondering something. Instead of writing `String.Format("{0:X}", num);` to convert numbers to hex. Is there a way where i could extend string directly so that i could simply write `num.ToHex();` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create extension method:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static string ToHex(this int source)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:X}", source);
    }
}
```

Execute like this:

```
string hexNum = 1234.ToHex();
```

Comment: What if `num` is not a string ?

Comment: and this could be done on any type by simply switching the StringExtensions to FloatExtensions for an example?

Comment: Ofiris it was to fast to answer, so I've used wrong datatype, but I've already edited my answer. @ThomasAndreèLian yeah, this could also be used for floats, but you will have to change `ToHex(this int source)` to `ToHex(this double source)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). However, it should be set on numeric type, to allow [`{0:X}` string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToHex(this int source)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:X}", source);
    }
}
```